Analytic solution for equations with non integer polynomial order
I need to quantize the general function $f(x) = a^{-x^b}$ in some arbitrary range from 0 till any m for my program. To do this I calculate a list of ordered xs whoose y values are some set % of the previous value. I do this so that the change in y values does not get too large relatively.
I tried to find such values analytically by solving $f(x)/f(x+r) = t$ where $t$ is the tolerance between 0 and 1 and $r$ is the displacement from the current $x$ such that $x+r$ is at said tolerance. After some algebra I eventually end up at $x^b-(x+y)^b=log_{a} (1-t)$. Is there any way to express this equation in terms of y?
The main problem im facing is that $b$ may be any positive rational number

Do you mean just to solve that equation for $y$? If so, then it's just $y = (x^b - \log_a(1-t))^{1/b} - x$

@MPW Yes! Thanks

I will convert this comment to an answer

To solve this equation for $y$, try to isolate $y$ step by step:
$$x^b-(x+y)^b=\log_{a} (1-t)$$
$$(x+y)^b = x^b - \log_{a} (1-t)$$
$$x+y = \left[x^b - \log_{a} (1-t)\right]^{1/b}$$
$$y = \boxed{ \left[x^b - \log_{a} (1-t)\right]^{1/b} - x }$$
This assumes all steps are reasonably defined. It looks like your $x$ and $y$ are positive, so it should be fine.
